# What is a Clustered Surrogate Key in a DW and what is it used for?

Tags: t-sql, surrogate-key

What is a Clustered Surrogate Key in a DW and what is it used for?

What T-SQL code do I write to make a column in a dimtable a clustered surrogate key?

Comment: Clustered refers to index. There can only be one (or zero) clustered index in a table. Surrogate referes to the key - a surrogate key is not an actual part of the table data - like when you make a primary key an int identity column, unlike a natural key that's made up from one or more columns containing actual data. I have no idea what DW is.

Comment: Thank you Zohar, it helped.

DW short for Data Warehouse